# Python callback ctypes function with va_list

Tags: python, callback, ctypes, variadic-functions

I have a problem defining a callback function used by a dll to get the log of other functions of the dll.
Here are the c function:

```
typedef void (RTMP_LogCallback)(int level, const char *fmt, va_list);
void RTMP_LogPrintf(const char *format, ...);
```

Here is my python code:

```
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('bin/librtmp.dll')
CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_char_p, c_void_p)
def logCallBack(level, message, va_list):
    dll.RTMP_LogPrintf(message, va_list)
    return 0
```

The problem is that the log is dirty and unreadable:

```
    Parsed host    : ☺Parsed app     : ☺connect to stream
ÄßGj♫¨', ... connected, handshaking?ßGj♥: Type Answer   : 27DBEC?ßGjä?┼♣: Server Uptime : 2612204?ßGj♥: FMS Version   : 2612204.2612100.488283845.4882
83530?ßGj♥: Handshaking finished....ÄßGj♫¨', handshaked│°Gj♀☻: fd=2614284, size=2614180Invoking ▒?'ä°Gj♀☻: fd=2618556`÷Gjá%&: server BW = 2618572ä°Gj♀
☻: fd=2618556o÷Gjá%&: client BW = 2618572 2618468ä°Gj♀☻: fd=2618556?÷Gj, received ctrl. type: 2618572, len: 2618468?÷Gj, Stream Begin 2618572ä°Gj♀☻: f
d=26185568÷Gj, received: chunk size change to 2618572ä°Gj♀☻: fd=2618556N÷Gj♣☺, received: invoke 2618572 bytes(object begin)Property: <|±'☺>Property: <
|±'☺>Property: <|±'OBJECT>(object begin)Property: <,´'☺>Property: <,´'☺>Property: <,´'☺>(object end)Property: <|±'OBJECT>(object begin)Property: <,´'☺
>Property: <,´'☺>Property: <,´'☺>Property: <,´'OBJECT>(object begin)Property: <▄ý'☺>(object end)Property: <,´'☺>Property: <,´'☺>(object end)(object en
d)~÷Gjmt;, server invoking <☺>~÷Gj, received result for method call <☺>│°Gj♀☻: fd=2616844, size=2616740sending ctrl. type: 0x27f264│°Gj♀☻: fd=2616828,
 size=2616724│°Gj♀☻: fd=2616828, size=2616724Invoking ?‗'UsherToken: ú?B☻,☺│°Gj♀☻: fd=2617164, size=2617060Invoking )¶'ä°Gj♀☻: fd=2618556N÷Gj↔, receiv
ed: invoke 2618572 bytes(object begin)Property: <|±'☺>Property: <|±'☺>Property: NULLProperty: <|±'☺>(object end)~÷Gj?⌂;, server invoking <☺>~÷Gj8¶;, r
eceived result for method call <☺>¶÷Gj, seekTime=2617308, stopTime=2617204, sending play: â─↑?♥â╚*?e¶╔├U?ýâý►SVW?¨?w►?E*ëE??F♦┴Ó☻?┌??↨│°Gj♀☻: fd=26171
64, size=2617060Invoking )¶'sending ctrl. type: 0x27f264│°Gj♀☻: fd=2616828, size=2616724ä°Gj♀☻: fd=2618556N÷Gj%, received: invoke 2618572 bytes(object
 begin)Property: <|±'☺>Property: <|±'☺>Property: NULLProperty: <|±'☺>(object end)~÷Gj?⌂;, server invoking <☺>~÷Gj, received result id 2617308 without
matching requestä°Gj♀☻: fd=2618556?÷Gj, received ctrl. type: 2618572, len: 2618468?÷Gj☺, Stream Begin 2618572ä°Gj♀☻: fd=2618556N÷Gjö, received: invoke
 2618572 bytes(object begin)Property: <|±'☺>Property: <|±'☺>Property: NULLProperty: <|±'OBJECT>(object begin)Property: <,´'☺>Property: <,´'☺>Property:
 <,´'☺>Property: <,´'☺>(object end)(object end)~÷Gj?t;, server invoking <☺>~÷Gj┴t;, onStatus: ☺ä°Gj♀☻: fd=2618556N÷Gj?, received: invoke 2618572 bytes
(object begin)Property: <|±'☺>Property: <|±'☺>Property: NULLProperty: <|±'OBJECT>(object begin)Property: <,´'☺>Property: <,´'☺>Property: <,´'☺>Propert, ...etc
```

I also tried to print directly message like this:

```
def logCallBack(level, message, va_list):
    print message
    return 0
```

but this time, log are incomplete:

```
%s, ... connected, handshaking
%s: Type Answer   : %02X
%s: Server Uptime : %d
%s: FMS Version   : %d.%d.%d.%d
%s: Handshaking finished....
%s, handshaked
%s: fd=%d, size=%d
Invoking %s
%s: fd=%d
%s: server BW = %d
%s: fd=%d
%s: client BW = %d %d
%s: fd=%d
%s, received ctrl. type: %d, len: %d
... etc
```

Does anyone knows ho to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Gontran

**EDIT :**

according to this thread (http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/15901/197/), ctypes doesn't provide a way of dealing with varargs functions. I get this point. But why using the RTMP_LogPrintf() function doesn't work correctly? I've the impression that I'm passing to the right arguments.

For information, RTMP_LogPrintf() is defined like this:

```
void RTMP_LogPrintf(const char *format, ...)
{
    char str[MAX_PRINT_LEN]="";
    int len;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    len = vsnprintf(str, MAX_PRINT_LEN-1, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    if ( RTMP_debuglevel==RTMP_LOGCRIT )
        return;

    if ( !fmsg ) fmsg = stderr;

    if (neednl) {
        putc('\n', fmsg);
        neednl = 0;
    }

    if (len > MAX_PRINT_LEN-1)
          len = MAX_PRINT_LEN-1;
    fprintf(fmsg, "%s", str);
    if (str[len-1] == '\n')
        fflush(fmsg);
}
```

Comment: I see a sad face.. I know what that means `☺`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the type `va_list` can really be represented by `c_void_p` (which is an assumption that may be wrong).  Even so, the following call is wrong:

```
dll.RTMP_LogPrintf(message, va_list)
```

You are passing exactly two arguments here, and the second one is a `void *`.  This is the same mistake as you would do in C if you wrote

```
RTMP_LogPrintf(message, va_list);
```

which does not work either as expected.  That's why there are two different functions `printf()` and `vprintf()`.  In C there is no portable way to build a *call* with a variable number of arguments (only the *receiver* can accept a variable number of arguments).  In Python+ctypes you can of course do it, but you need to have the arguments available as a list of Python objects, not merely as one `va_list` object.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, POINTER(c_char), c_void_p)
```